# Recent activity bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity

When I click on the envelope icon, I see no activity for today. If I then click on *yesterday*, I see correctly the activity for yesterday. But when I then click on **today**, I see activity for today that was not there two clicks ago.

I see this in meta and Area 51 (don't have enough recent activity on other sites to know about them).

This is something I can consistently reproduce. I use Firefox (don't know if that is important).

This is probably related to (but not the same as) this defect: [Recent Activity Area of my Profile is bugged - “Today” and “Yesterday” sometimes don’t work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59114/recent-activity-area-of-my-profile-is-bugged-today-and-yesterday-sometimes)

**Update:** here is a directly related issue which I think *is* a bug: click the envelope icon then click reputation. **"Today" will be highlighted** but only **recent** information will be shown. But if you *click on "Today"*, then Today's info will be shown. This is different from the above because, in this case, "Today" is highlighted, implying that info from Today is displayed, which is not the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clicking envelope beside username shows fewer recent activities than "today" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/clicking-envelope-beside-username-shows-fewer-recent-activities-than-today-butt)

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56451/clicking-the-recent-activity-envelope-when-indicated-displays-no-activity-closed

Comment: Also related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/envelope-lighting-up-arbitrarily-and-unpredictably

Comment: @Ralph - the accepted answer to the first link says, "There was a really heinous long-standing bug with the replies envelope here **that we just fixed**." If this is the same, this issue is *not* resolved.

Comment: @Mark - ignore that part of the answer. The rest of the answer explains exactly what is happening now that the UTC bug has been fixed. Recent is not equal to Today, but only displays activity since last login. The question though is equivalent.

Comment: @Ralph - aha, thanks. (You reacted fast, thanks - I was distracted by my *real* work... =:-) ) Mind you, it still means that this bug is **not fixed** - if Today is highlighted, I expect to read about Today, not since last log in.

Comment: Blimey - another similar issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28393/clicking-envelope-recent-different-then-clicking-today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the fact that this "bug" is reported countless times, I think that it's fair to assume that the enveloppe's behaviour is **not intuitive**. If I see a "recent activity" notification, then I'd surely expect to see them once I click the notification and certainly not an empty overview which requires one extra handling. This is plain bad UX.

Comment: UX = user experience

Comment: The SO devvers know that :)

Comment: I contribute there as well and it was new for me. =:-)

Answer (score 2):

When you first click on the envelope icon, you're not supposed to see today, you're supposed to see 'recent activity' (search Meta for that exact definition).  You have to actually click on 'Today' to get today's activity.

Comment: thank you, I tested your answer and it is correct. Seems weird though, that nothing is selected by default. (I couldn't find the "recent activity" definition.)

Comment: @Mark, I think it's the activity from when you started your session, but I can never remember exactly.